# Managed HttpListener vs C++ Network Lib - Requires admin rights?

Tags: c#, windows, http, listener

So, I have noticed that starting an HttpListener is considered impolite according to Win 7. I cannot do so without administrative rights without adding myself to some URL reservation list. In theory, this is alright, but I'd like to make my program as little invasive as possible.

My main other alternative is something like the c++ Network Library, which utilizes boost. This is probably not as simple as a HttpListener though. Will this circumvent the admin rights requirement for listening to some HTTP url?

How does windows handle http listening? Right now I'm just listening to `http://+:xxxx/url`, I guess it's fully possible to just create a Socket listening at port xxxx and provide my own/third party http implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly provide your own implementation (that's what www.fiddler2.com and FiddlerCore both do). When you use the HttpListener, the listening task is handed off to the http.sys system component (also used by IIS, etc).